# Is it possible to set the scroll position of an element using flexbox display model?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material, which uses the Flexbox display model, to build a web app. The scroll position of the <body> is at (0,0) as the app is "full-page," but I'd like to add a button in the toolbar to scroll to the top of the main content <div>. Not sure it's possible as I don't think the Flexbox API exposes to JavaScript the ability to do so.

Attempted solutions:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
document.getElementById('elementId').scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Please show us some code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

My HTML looked like the following:

```
<div id="main" layout="column" flex>
    <md-toolbar></md-toolbar>
    <md-content></md-toolbar>
</div>
```

I tried targeting the `<div>` and using JavaScript to scroll to the top as so:

```
document.getElementById('main').scrollTop = 0;
```

But that wouldn't work as the `<div id="main">`'s `scrollTop` value was equal to 0, as it's a full-page webapp.

I moved the `id` attribute to the `<md-content>` element:

```
<div layout="column" flex>
    <md-toolbar></md-toolbar>
    <md-content id="main"></md-toolbar>
</div>
```

And in my controller, I injected the "$window" service to get a hook on the "document" object to more appropriately get a hook onto the element:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Controller', Controller);

Controller.$inject = ['$window', ...];

function Controller($window, ...) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.scrollToTop = scrollToTop;

    ...

    function scrollToTop(elementId) {
        $window.document.getElementById(elementId).scrollTop = 0;
    }

    ...
}
```